# Why is the output of my C++ conv-function not the same as in the conv Matlab call?

Tags: c++, algorithm, matlab, convolution

So, I've implemented my own convolution function and compared its output to the one of the Matlab [conv](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html#responsive_offcanvas) function.

Specifically, I want the output of the `conv( [0.1, 0.23, 0.25, 0.18, 0.09], [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0], 'same')` call to be the same as to what is written in `output` after calling `conv({0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0}, 2, 6, {0.1, 0.23, 0.25, 0.18, 0.09}, 5, 5, output);`.

Here is my code (it asssumes that the signal is already padded, which is why I have the _start and _stop thingy)

```
void conv(double* signal, int conv_start, int conv_stop, double* kernel, int kernel_len, int output_len, double* output){   
    int halfKernel = floor(kernel_len/2.0);
    for (int i = 0; i<output_len; i++) output[i] = 0;
    for (int c = conv_start; c<=conv_stop; c++){
        for (int k = -halfKernel; k <=halfKernel; k++){ 
            output[c-conv_start] += kernel[k+halfKernel]*signal[c+k];
        }
    }
}
```

And the output of the Matlab-function is:
`1.0100   1.7700   2.6200   2.8700   2.2400`

While mine is:
`0.880000   1.630000    2.480000    2.790000    2.470000`.

I've done the calculation with the above input also by hand and then I get the same result as my own implementation. So, is this a conceptual error or is the Matlab function not doing what I think it is supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, since you wrote the function, it makes sense that your hand calculations turn out the same. Furthermore, it is a hint that indeed this is a conceptual error.

In convolution, the kernel should be reflected around the middle (or flipped if you wish). So you can do something like:

```
output[c-conv_start] += kernel[(kernel_len -1) - (k+halfKernel)]*signal[c+k];
```